# Getting SearchView from MenuItem returns View and not SearchView

Tags: android, menuitem, searchview

I'm trying to fetch my SearchView from the Toolbar within a Fragment.

Im infalting a menu item in the onCreateOptionsMenu.

**Problem** : searchItem.getActionView() returns a "View" and not a "SearchView". See code below

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = searchItem.getActionView(); // This one is red - "returns View, should return Searchview"
}
```

XML for menu item (menu_search.xml):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:title="@string/search"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: yes, `getActionView()` returns `View`, why should it return `SearchView`? you can set any `View` as your "action view", can't you?

Comment: But isn't the actionView the same like the actionViewClass? And then should return a SearchView? If not - how to grab this SearchView menu item from the toolbar?

Comment: see answer below - by simple cast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search.getActionView();
```

Comment: Ok, so it has to be cast as a SearchView. Thanks. Accepted answer